# Networking with Multiple Nics

Tags: 12.04, networking

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server with 4 Network adapters in it. I need to use each NIC for a separate function. Here is a description of my setup:

```
etho = 10.234.0.2 netmask = 255.255.255.252 gw = 10.234.0.1 This is on vlan 234
eth1 = 10.235.0.2 netmask = 255.255.255.252 gw = 10.235.0.1 This is on vlan 235
eth2 = 10.236.0.2 netmask = 255.255.255.252 gw = 10.236.0.1 This is on vlan 236
eth3 = 10.237.0.2 netmask = 255.255.255.252 gw = 10.237.0.1 This is on vlan 237
```

I need to be able to direct traffic to and from the individual IP addresses for separate web services. ie 10.235.0.2 is a website, 10.236.0.2 is a different site, and 10.237.0.2 is a third site. The 1st IP is for management of the server.

I think the issue is a routing issue, but I am new enough to Linux to not have a full understanding of the ins and outs of the routing capabilities.

Here is what is in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# WWW Management
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.234.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.252
gateway 10.234.0.1
nameseervers 10.230.1.103, 10.230.70.70

# WWW
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.235.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.252
gateway 10.235.0.1

# WTB
#auto eth2
#iface eth2 inet static
#address 10.236.0.2
#netmask 255.255.255.252
#gateway 10.236.0.1

# Moodle
#auto eth3
#iface eth3 inet static
#address 10.237.0.2
#netmask 255.255.255.252
#gateway 10.237.0.1
```

I have disabled the last two networks just to ease confusion.

Thanks in advance for all of the help and comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After doing a normal configuration of just eth0, I came back around and added config for eth1. With just eth0 up, the route table was:

```
# ip route show
192.168.0.96/27 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.126
default via 192.168.0.97 dev eth0 metric 100
```

But once I brought up eth1, the order of the default route statements determined which interface was always used. As shown below, it happens to choose the eth1 route to the 192.168.1.65 gateway.

```
# ip route show
192.168.0.96/27 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.126
192.168.1.64/27 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.93
default via 192.168.1.65 dev eth1 metric 100
default via 192.168.0.97 dev eth0 metric 100
```

### only one gateway statement

The first problem can be the extra 'via 192.168.1.65' default route. It appears there if the eth1 definition in /etc/network/interfaces has a "gateway 192.168.1.65" statement. So remove any extra gateway statement, and bounce the interface:

```
# ifdown eth1
# ifup eth1
# ip route show
192.168.0.96/27 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.126
192.168.1.64/27 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.93
default via 192.168.0.97 dev eth0 metric 100
```

### setup new routing table

Create a new, seperate routing table containing a default route appropriate for all traffic flowing out of eth1. The table number here is not important; 101 is simply not the main routing table. Do this with a 'post-up' command on the eth1 configuration in /etc/network/interfaces. Add only one post-up on eth1; Do not add it to any of the eth1: sub-interfaces.

```
post-up ip route add default via 192.168.1.65 dev eth1 table 101
```

Bounce eth1. The main routing table is unchanged, and table 101 will contain the via 192.168.1.65 default route if eth1 is up.

```
# ifdown eth1
# ip route show
192.168.0.96/27 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.126
default via 192.168.0.97 dev eth0 metric 100

# ip route show table 101   (ie, table is empty, no output)
# ifup eth1
# ip route show
192.168.0.96/27 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.126
192.168.1.64/27 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.93
default via 192.168.0.97 dev eth0 metric 100

# ip route show table 101
default via 192.168.1.65 dev eth1
```

### new routing rule

Add a routing rule to use table 101 to select a default route for packets which should go out eth1.

```
# ip rule add from 192.168.1.64/27 lookup 101
# ip rule show
0:     from all lookup local
32765: from 192.168.1.64/27 lookup 101
32766: from all lookup main
32767: from all lookup default
```

Add the rule to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file as well:

```
post-up ip rule add from 192.168.1.64/27 lookup 101
```

Now make sure to add cleanup to remove the route and rule when the interface goes down:

```
post-down ip rule del from 192.168.1.64/27
post-down ip route del default via 192.168.1.65 table 101
```

[EDIT for ubuntu 16.04+]
Like indicated [here](https://api.queryxchange.com/q/3_793877/apply-static-ip-address-change-in-etc-network-interfaces-in-ubuntu-16-04/) and from test I've made from this help, ip route2 have changed his structure of commands.
For making work you will have to adapt just a bit to do in the order how the `man ip` [points](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ip).

```
up ip route add default table 101 dev eth1 via 192.168.1.65
up ip rule add from 192.168.1.64/27 lookup 101
down ip rule del from 192.168.1.64/27
down ip route del default table 101 via 192.168.1.65
```

Or you will end up after a ifdown - ifup command with a error message @ifdown command(standard message to say that the peripherals is not correctly configured), and @ifup the absence of a route in table 101.

Comment: Nice, but I don't like to use rc.local .. looking for a more elegant final step ..

Comment: It was edited I suppose :) ..

Comment: Is there actually an /etc/interfaces file, or is that a typo?

Comment: @user100464 `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: There is a ref to the former in the answer.  I can't edit it.